# Access angularjs services from a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added some code to block user interaction while angular $http requests are in-progress:

**controller.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("my_app", ["my_app"]);
app.controller("MyController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.blocking = false;
  $scope.do_something = function() {
    $scope.blocking = true;
    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.url.com",
      data: my_data
    }).success(function(data) {
      // do something nice
    }).error(function(data) {
      // do some error handling
    }).finally(function() {
      $scope.blocking = false;
    });
  };
}]);
```

**template.html:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <fieldset ng-disabled="blocking">
    <form>
      ...a bunch of form elements...
      ...including a "submit" button...
      ...some of which call "do_something" above...
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

When I run the "do_something" fn this correctly sets "blocking" to true which has the effect of preventing all user interaction inside the fieldset.  Hooray.

*However*, my code needs to do this sort of thing a lot.  So I tried to move the functionality to a service:

**service.js:**

```
app.factory('$my_service', ['$http', function($http) {
  _blocking = false;
  return {
    getBlocking: function() {
      return _blocking;
    },
    setBlocking: function(blocking) {
      _blocking = blocking;
    }
  }
}]);
```

Then my "do_something" fn above simply calls $my_service.setBlocking as needed.  However, I don't know what to put for the argument of ng-disabled.

Any suggestions?

---

As requested by @user449689, here is the new controller code:

```
app.controller("MyController", ['$scope', '$http', '$my_service', function($scope, $http, $my_service) {
  $scope.do_something = function() {
    $my_service.setBlocking(true);
    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.url.com",
      data: my_data
    }).success(function(data) {
      // do something nice
    }).error(function(data) {
      // do some error handling
    }).finally(function() {
      $my_service.setBlocking(false);
    });
  };
}]);
```

But I can't figure out what to put in the "ng-disabled" attribute of the fieldset element.

Comment: show us the new code in which you call the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your `$scope.blocking` on the controller to reference the service method `$my_service.getBlocking` and update the HTML to

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="blocking()">
```

On controller

```
$scope.blocking = $my_service.getBlocking
```

Comment: D'oh!  It's so simple.  Thanks very much for your help.